# Implementação de uma search box

Tags: javascript

Boa noite,

Relativamente à pouco tempo aprendi HTML5 e CSS3 e de momento estou a aprender JavaScript. Estou a criar uma página web mas estou com dificuldades na parte da criação da search box. Eu já a tenho criada (usei a tag input com name="search") mas não sei como fazê-la procurar pelo conteúdo da página. Se pudessem ajudar agradecia muito.

Obrigado

Comment: Você logo vai descobrir que isso é mais difícil do que parece... O seu `name="search"` não significa nada em especial para o navegador ou para o servidor que receberá a requisição, e nada que diga para eles realizarem alguma espécie de busca.

Comment: Aproveite e dê uma lida em [https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Atributos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Atributos), já que estamos falando em atributos de `<input>`

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo do que queres que aconteça quando inseres texto que encontra algo? queres marcar o texto?, queres perguntar no servidor por texto? queres mostrar ao utilizador palavras encontradas junto ao input?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que todos os internautas saibam como fazer uma busca na página pois quase todos os navegadores de internet possuem uma ferramenta de busca que permite pesquisar palavras ou frases correspondentes nas páginas acessadas. Basta teclar Ctrl+f (windows) ou Command+F (Mac) que uma caixa de pesquisa surgirá.

Mas também é possível com poucas linhas de códigos implementar essa caixa de busca na página.

CSS

```
 .found {background-color:#f99;}
 #searchbox {width:350px; position:absolute;
 _top:expression(document.body.scrollTop+document.body.clientHeight-this.clientHeight-10);
 left:0; top:0;}
 body > #searchbox {position:Fixed;}
 #searchbox fieldset {border:0;text-align:center;margin:3px;}
 #searchbox input {margin:1px;padding:2px;}
 #search {width:140px;}
```

JavaScript

```
inPageSearch = function() {document.getElementsByClassName = function(cl) {var retnode, myclass, elem,classes; retnode = []; myclass = new RegExp('\\b'+cl+'\\b'); elem = this.getElementsByTagName('*'); for (var i = 0, ii = elem.length ; i < ii ; i++) {classes = elem[i].className; if (myclass.test(classes)) retnode.push(elem[i]);} return retnode;}; elemTop = function(elem) {return elem.top || elem.pixelTop || elem.offsetTop || 0;}; search = function(str) {nodewalk = function(node, str) {var re, m, s, r, frag, sp; for (var i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {if (node[i].hasChildNodes() && 'SCRIPT' !== node[i].nodeName) nodewalk(node[i].childNodes,str); re = new RegExp(str,'ig'); if (3 === node[i].nodeType) {m = node[i].nodeValue.match(re); s = node[i].nodeValue.split(re); frag = document.createDocumentFragment(); if (m !== null) {frag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s[0])); for (var j = 0, jj = m.length; j < jj; j++) {sp = document.createElement('span'); sp.appendChild(document.createTextNode(m[j])); sp.className = 'found'; frag.appendChild(sp);frag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s[j+1]));} node[i].parentNode.replaceChild(frag,node[i]);i+=jj*2;}}}}; nodewalk(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].childNodes, str);}; clearfound = function(node) {var txt = node.previousSibling.nodeValue + node.firstChild.nodeValue + node.nextSibling.nodeValue; node.parentNode.removeChild(node.nextSibling); node.parentNode.removeChild(node.previousSibling); node.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(txt), node);}; var d, F, fld, inp, b1, b2, b3; d =document.createElement("div"); d.id = 'searchbox';  F = document.createElement("form"); fld = document.createElement("fieldset"); inp = document.createElement("input"); inp.type = 'text'; inp.id = 'search'; fld.appendChild(inp); b1 = document.createElement("input"); b1.type = 'button'; b1.id = 'search1'; b1.value = 'Search'; b1.title = 'Buscar todos'; fld.appendChild(b1); F.appendChild(fld); d.appendChild(F); document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(d); document.getElementById('search1').onclick = function() {var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('found'); for (var i = nodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) clearfound(nodes[i]); search(document.getElementById('search').value); window.scrollTo(0, elemTop(document.getElementsByClassName('found')[0])); return false;}; document.getElementById('search2').onclick = function() {var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('found'); clearfound(nodes[0]); window.scrollTo(0, elemTop(document.getElementsByClassName('found')[0])); return false;};
document.getElementById('searchx').onclick = function() {var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('found'); for (var i = nodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) clearfound(nodes[i]); document.getElementById('searchbox').style.display = 'none'; setTimeout(function() {document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].removeChild(document.getElementById('searchbox'));},5);};};

inPageSearch();
```

> Se você quiser que a caixa de pesquisa apareça quando a página for carregada use

`<body onload="inPageSearch ()">`

> Se preferir abrir a caixa de pesquisa através de link use

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="inPageSearch ()">Search</a>
```

[Atalhos de teclado do Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=pt-BR)

[Mozilla support - Como buscar por textos e links no conteúdo de uma página](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Learn-the-Basics-get-started/Como-buscar-por-textos-e-links-no-conte%C3%BAdo-de-uma-p%C3%A1gina/ta-p/8155)

[[Microsoft Edge] - Teclas de atalho](https://answers.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/wiki/apps_windows_10-msedge/microsoft-edge-teclas-de-atalho/48d4562d-3b14-4703-9fbb-5ed092684490)